# Three JS white screen when loading JSON object

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I downloaded `threejs` and now try to create a `3D environment` where you can move freely in some kind of "ego perspective". I used the pointlock-control example as submission and now I'm on to add my own stuff starting with a car created in Blender and exported as `JSON` but every time I try to load it I get just a white screen. I hope you guys can help me.

Code:

```
    <style>
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: arial;
        }

        #blocker {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        }

        #instructions {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -moz-box;
            display: box;
            -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
            -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
            box-orient: horizontal;
            -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -moz-box-pack: center;
            box-pack: center;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -moz-box-align: center;
            box-align: center;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controls/PointerLockControls.js"></script>
    <div id="blocker">
        <div id="instructions">
            <span style="font-size:40px">Click to move</span>
            <br />
            (WASD or Arrow Keys = Move, SPACE = Jump, MOUSE = Look around)
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var geometry, material, mesh;
        var loader;
        var auto;
        var loadModel;
        var controls,time = Date.now();
        var objects = [];
        var ray;
        var blocker = document.getElementById( 'blocker' );
        var instructions = document.getElementById( 'instructions' );

        // http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pointerlock/intro/
        var havePointerLock = 'pointerLockElement' in document || 'mozPointerLockElement' in document || 'webkitPointerLockElement' in document;

        if ( havePointerLock ) {
            var element = document.body;
            var pointerlockchange = function ( event ) {
                if ( document.pointerLockElement === element || document.mozPointerLockElement === element || document.webkitPointerLockElement === element ) {
                    controls.enabled = true;
                    blocker.style.display = 'none';
                } else {
                    controls.enabled = false;
                    blocker.style.display  = '-webkit-box';
                    blocker.style.display = '-moz-box';
                    blocker.style.display = 'box';
                    instructions.style.display = '';
                }
            }

            var pointerlockerror = function ( event ) {
                instructions.style.display = '';
            }

            // Hook pointer lock state change events
            document.addEventListener( 'pointerlockchange', pointerlockchange, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mozpointerlockchange', pointerlockchange, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'webkitpointerlockchange', pointerlockchange, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'pointerlockerror', pointerlockerror, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mozpointerlockerror', pointerlockerror, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'webkitpointerlockerror', pointerlockerror, false );
            instructions.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {
                instructions.style.display = 'none';
                // Ask the browser to lock the pointer
                element.requestPointerLock = element.requestPointerLock || element.mozRequestPointerLock || element.webkitRequestPointerLock;

                if ( /Firefox/i.test( navigator.userAgent ) ) {
                    var fullscreenchange = function ( event ) {
                        if ( document.fullscreenElement === element || document.mozFullscreenElement === element || document.mozFullScreenElement === element ) {
                            document.removeEventListener( 'fullscreenchange', fullscreenchange );
                            document.removeEventListener( 'mozfullscreenchange', fullscreenchange );
                            element.requestPointerLock();
                        }
                    }
                    document.addEventListener( 'fullscreenchange', fullscreenchange, false );
                    document.addEventListener( 'mozfullscreenchange', fullscreenchange, false );
                    element.requestFullscreen = element.requestFullscreen || element.mozRequestFullscreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullscreen;
                    element.requestFullscreen();
                } else {
                    element.requestPointerLock();
                }
            }, false );
        } else {
            instructions.innerHTML = 'Your browser doesn\'t seem to support Pointer Lock API';
        }
        init();
        animate();
        function init() {
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xffffff, 0, 750 );
            var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1.5 );
            light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
            scene.add( light );
            var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.75 );
            light.position.set( -1, - 0.5, -1 );
            scene.add( light );
            controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls( camera );
            scene.add( controls.getObject() );
            ray = new THREE.Raycaster();
            ray.ray.direction.set( 0, -1, 0 );

            // floor
            geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 2000, 2000, 100, 100 );
            geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( - Math.PI / 2 ) );

            for ( var i = 0, l = geometry.vertices.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
                var vertex = geometry.vertices[ i ];
                vertex.x += Math.random() * 20 - 10;
                vertex.y += Math.random() * 2;
                vertex.z += Math.random() * 20 - 10;
            }

            for ( var i = 0, l = geometry.faces.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
                var face = geometry.faces[ i ];
                face.vertexColors[ 0 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );
                face.vertexColors[ 1 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );
                face.vertexColors[ 2 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );
                face.vertexColors[ 3 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );
            }

            material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } );
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( mesh );

            // objects
                    loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(  );
    loadModel = function(geometry) 
        {                        
            auto = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { envMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/metal.jpg', new THREE.SphericalReflectionMapping() ), overdraw: true, shading: THREE.SmoothShading } ) );
            mesh.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
            mesh.position.set(0, 150, 0);
            //mesh.rotation.set(Math.PI/2, Mat.PI/2, Math.PI/2);
            //mesh.matrix.setRotationFromEuler(mesh.rotation);
            scene.add( auto );
        };
    loader.load('blender.js/auto.js', loadModel );
    setInterval(render, 50);

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        }

        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            controls.isOnObject( false );
            ray.ray.origin.copy( controls.getObject().position );
            ray.ray.origin.y -= 10;
            var intersections = ray.intersectObjects( objects );
            if ( intersections.length > 0 ) {
                var distance = intersections[ 0 ].distance;
                if ( distance > 0 && distance < 10 ) {
                    controls.isOnObject( true );
                }
            }
            controls.update( Date.now() - time );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
            time = Date.now();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`var intersections = ray.intersectObjects( objects );` but you aren't adding your mesh to objects.

Answer (score 0):

Background color of body and text "color" in instructions is same #ffffff in style.

Please change one of them, and then try :)

It may be giving out put but you may not see it,

Update:

You are adding scene here `scene.add(mesh2);` I think we should follow the  working code(below) and redraw the scene(using loop or timer, every "0.05 second"), don't add new scene, use simple example like round to move then proceed with complex car, that may confuse sometimes..

Working Code:

```
loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loadModel = function (geometry) {
    mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                envMap : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/metal.refl.jpg', new THREE.SphericalReflectionMapping()),
                overdraw : true,
                shading : THREE.SmoothShading
            }));
    mesh2.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
    mesh2.position.set(0, 0, 0); 
    //mesh.rotation.set(Math.PI/2, Mat.PI/2, Math.PI/2); 
    //mesh.matrix.setRotationFromEuler(mesh.rotation); 
    scene.add( mesh2 ); 
};
```

Comment if not solved using this

Comment: controls.update( Date.now() - time );

     renderer.render( scene, camera );

     time = Date.now();

Do you thin "time" is defined before its use??, try without its use, i think its not of any use, if you are trying date.now() -time; where time = date.now() so that may lead to zero( theorotically) try skipping these steps..

Comment: when i skip these steps i cant move anymore just the camera

Comment: I think you have said in beginning its point lock control example.
ONly camera moves that is perfect scenario, right ??

Comment: no i want to move with wasd/arrow keys too not just view around and when i keep the steps with controls.update i can move

Comment: Then how can you lock points? you need to change points in that case? I hope this makes sense, or else you need to "redraw the scene", again and again, like we move slides while playing movie, that will create moving object effect.

Comment: the lock point is the same as in the example and it's working the problem i think is the json loader cause everytime I try to load the car i get white srceen but when i make this part as comment it works

Comment: loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(  );
        loadModel = function(geometry) 
   {       
                mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { envMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/metal.refl.jpg', new THREE.SphericalReflectionMapping() ), overdraw: true, shading: THREE.SmoothShading } ) );
    mesh2.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
    mesh2.position.set(0, 0, 0);
                //mesh.rotation.set(Math.PI/2, Mat.PI/2, Math.PI/2);
                //mesh.matrix.setRotationFromEuler(mesh.rotation);
    scene.add( mesh2 );
            };

Comment: above is the code about the import of the car and with this code i dont get white screen but cant see the car aswell

Answer (score 0):

Your camera does not have position nor target.

Comment: but why does it work without the json model loaded ? when i delete the part from "loader = ... " to "loader.load" i see the floor and everything and when i try to load the json car screen gets black

Comment: tried to give the camera a position and target but just got white screen aswell